# Is it essential to close the database?

Tags: android, sqlite

In Google's Notepad Example, they don't seem to close the database, at least not in onDestroy().

What is the purpose of closing it, and do I really need to?  Does an open database take up significant memory?  I have found that closing it in onDestroy leaves vulnerabilities if there are any threads running that might try to access it after the Activity is finished.

Comment: did my answer get accepted and then unaccepted?

Comment: I was trying to accept it on my phone...I guess this site is a bit buggy on the Android browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't close the database connections, they'll cause memory leaks over time.

The Notepad example does use `startManagingCursor`, but you still need to explicitly close the db connection.  Run the Notepad example as-is and edit several notes in succession, you'll see that it starts throwing Warnings and Errors in LogCat.  (In larger applications, you'll also start to see Memory Leak Detection warnings.)

```
W/SQLiteCompiledSql(  302): Releasing statement in a finalizer. Please ensure that you explicitly call close() on your cursor: INSERT INTO notes(body, title) VALUES(?, ?);
W/SQLiteCompiledSql(  302): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
W/SQLiteCompiledSql(  302):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:62)
...
W/SQLiteCompiledSql(  302):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/Database(  302): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.android.demo.notepad3/databases/data' 
E/Database(  302): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
E/Database(  302):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
...
E/Database(  302):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

You mentioned that closing it in `onDestroy()` "leaves vulnerabilities" in any non-UI threads that are still running.  If you're using AsyncTask, you can check the status of of these threads using `getStatus` on your tasks.

```
if ( myAsyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED ){
    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

Then close the connection in the `onPostExecute` method of your `AsyncTask`.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Wow..I never thought Google's own examples would use inoptimal code!

Comment: Can you close the DB before the cursor safely? Thanks.

Comment: @TenFour04 - No.  It will pitch a fit if you close the DB and then try to access the cursor.  If it's not on the UI thread, I do not believe it crashes the app - but it's still bad form.

Answer (score 0):

You should close it.

The notepad example should be using `Activity`'s [startManagingCursor](http://bit.ly/hGw67k).

Comment: That takes care of the cursor, but what about the SQLiteDatabase object?