# Android: Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have an application which requires the use of SQLite (Android's database).

I have created a JPA-like structure to my model and datahelper.
The problem is when I call another aHelper.search(int id) while on a helper.search(int id), the Finalizing a Cursor error logs.

```
return Child(cursor.getInt(0), new ParentHelper.search(cursor.getInt(1)));
```

The structure to my JPA-like model and datahelper goes like this.

```
class Parent {
   int id;
   String name
   // constructor with field-parameter
   // getters and setters
}

class Child {
   int id;
   Parent parent;
   // constructor with field-parameter
   // getters and setters
}

class ParentHelper {
   // necessary SQLiteImpelemntations
   Parent search(int id) {
      // new Cursor implementation
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      return new Parent(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1));
   }
}

class ChildHelper {

   ParentHelper parentHelper;

   void close() {
      parenHelper.close()
      SQLiteDatabase.close();
      SQLiteOpenHelper.close();
   }

   ArrayList searchAll() {
      // new Cursor implementation
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      Child child = new Child(cursor.getInt(0), parentHelper.search(cursor.getInt(1)))
      ArrayList.add(child)
      cursor.close();
   }

   // necessary SQLiteImpelemntations
   Child search(int id) {
      // new Cursor implemenation
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      Child child = new Child(cursor.getInt(0), parentHelper.search(cursor.getInt(1)))
      cursor.close();
      return child;
   }   
}
```

Comment: Updated to code. Stuck when running multiple Cursor's (like in JPA) in hierarchical manner. Child.search().Cursor with Parent.search().Cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing your Cursor before returning the value.

```
class ParentHelper {
// necessary SQLiteImpelemntations
Parent search(int id) {
    // new Cursor implementation
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Parent p = new Parent(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1));
    cursor.close();
    return p;
    }
}
```

Do the same for your ChildHelper.

Comment: The error has changed to "close() was never explicitly called on database".

Comment: I don't know where you get this error, but you should try closing your SQLiteDatabase variable at some point (SQLiteDatabase db; db.close();)

Comment: Strange it seemed. But when I tried to close the instance of another helper. It doesn't changed a thing. How can I solve this then?

Comment: I can't tell where you have to close your database without more information. Have a look at these questions, they may help you:   [Question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707713/close-was-never-explicitly-called), [Question2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972145/is-it-essential-to-close-the-database)

Comment: Regarding question1: basing from my code, I'm opening another cursor from a running one; question2: since according to some, startManagingCursor is deprecated [not sure on 2.2], I can't use the suggested answer.