# Android Memory Leak With Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks

So I developed a simple application as part of an independent qualification and it works great, so I published it and uploaded the apk to the Play Store. The download I can get from the Play Store works fine, and everything's good.

I come back a week or so later to my project files, to add an update for my app, and upon running it (no changes made) I'm now getting what seems memory leaks.

This hadn't happened before and upon reverting to even older versions of my app they all now exhibit this issue.

When switching between fragments(I have three in total, and one has only a textview on it, with no code) using the default Android navigation bar template, they appear to flicker - the transition is not seamless and smooth like my final apk downloaded from the Play Store.

In addition, in the logcats I find the following message as I switch between the fragments:

```
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=92KB
I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

This repeats as I continue to do this, and memory usage in the profiler increases too.

I also see this message occasionally:

```
I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 8MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
```

I'm very new to Android development but this appears, from what I can tell, to be a memory leak.

I find it very strange that my app no longer works yet my apk file still runs perfectly. I'm running everything on my Android phone, which was recently updated to Oreo(could this be the cause)?

Hopefully somebody with knowledge on the causes of Android memory leaks could help me out here.

I'm happy to provide code, but in a summary, my application is very simple and contains 3 fragments, with a RecyclerView attached to a SQLite database in one of them, and the other has two buttons and an ImageView.

This project is due in 2 weeks, and this issue upon returning to development has me pulling my hair out!

Thanks.

As requested, here is my code for opening fragments depending on which navmenu item was selected (this is located in the MainActivity)

```
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = "";

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_tasks) {
            fragment = new TaskFragment();
            title = "Tasks";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_alarm) {
            fragment = new AlarmFragment();
            title = "Alarms";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            title = "Settings";
        }

        if(fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            ft.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment);
            ft.commit();

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is my code for the fragment which houses the RecyclerView, and the references to my SQLite database. In addition, there is a fab which opens a new activity, but I feel this is not causing any issues as the flickering and memory increases are purely when switching between any of the 3 fragments.

```
//task page code

public class TaskFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private TaskAdapter taskAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //db
        TaskDBHelper dbHelper = new TaskDBHelper(TaskFragment.this.getActivity());
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(TaskFragment.this.getActivity()));
        taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(TaskFragment.this.getActivity(), getAllItems());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                removeItem((long) viewHolder.itemView.getTag());
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        //

        view.findViewById(R.id.add_task_fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openAddTask();
            }

        });

    }

    private void removeItem(long id) {
        db.delete(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + "=" + id, null );
        taskAdapter.swapCursor(getAllItems());
    }

    public Cursor getAllItems() {
        TaskDBHelper dbHelper = new TaskDBHelper(TaskFragment.this.getActivity());
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(
                TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC"
        );
    }

    public void openAddTask() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TaskFragment.this.getActivity(), AddTask.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                taskAdapter.swapCursor(getAllItems());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: If you want to track memory leaks you can try [https://github.com/square/leakcanary/](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/)

Comment: I've tried that, but I don't have an application class and even when making one, LeakCanary doesn't seem to show up at all when running in debug mode

Comment: Based on what you provided I'd say the problem is either in the way you instantiate your Fragment or in the Fragment linked to the database (as you said there is nothing but TextView is the two others). Please add your code

Comment: I've added code for you, Eselfar.

Comment: Guess it's because you're not closing your access to the database. Have a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986732/1827254

Comment: Where would you recommend I close the database? Do I simply add an onDestroy method? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious in that post. 

In addition, the other activity in my project - the one which adds to the database using inputs on that activity also uses the database. Shall I close it there too?

Thank you for your help, hopefully you can bear with my lack of knowledge with this.

Comment: You need to close the access as soon as you don't need it. But as you are recreating the access each time the view is created (in `onViewCreated`) you should at least close the access in `onDestroyView`. As reminder https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/101826485820997153590/5914215085941005954

Comment: I've added db.close(); to both an onDestroyView method in my fragment, and the other activity before I call finish();

However, this seems to have had no effect. When changing between my second and third fragments this flickering (fast black screen) and memory leak happens too, and neither of these fragments contain any db access.

Comment: In `onDestroyView` do `taskAdapter=null;` as the Adapter has a reference to the Activity

Comment: Did you try [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html) to investigate what's leaking?

Comment: Is this what you mean by the investigation?
https://i.imgur.com/s9IAVXs.png

Comment: Yes. You should be able to see if old versions of the Fragment are still retained and potentially why

Comment: I don't seem to understand how to analyse the .hprof file - in the analyser tasks section I can't click the run button for detecting leaked activities for some reason and I can't seem to find any meaningful data from the FinalizerReference class, which I presume is causing the leak. Any help?

Comment: I've also attempted using Eclipse's memory analyser and found this:
https://i.imgur.com/ws88TOi.png